# What are the Ethereum 2.0 testnets?

Tags: testnets, eth-2.0, beacon-chain, medalla, spadina

There are many different Ethereum 2.0 testnets, among them

- Medalla
- Spadina
- Zinken

What are the differences and what is their purpose?

Comment: Zinken? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87952/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-zinken-ethereum-2-0-testnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ethereum 2.0 testnets can be categorized in different stages of testing, varying in their complexity of operation.

0. semi-public devnets
1. single-client testnets
2. multi-client testnets
3. semi-public attacknets
4. post-launch testnets

#### semi-public devnets

While implementing the Ethereum 2.0 protocol and before announcing releases, the core client developers maintain their semi-public testnets to develop and test the protocol against.

The first documented devnets in late 2019 were:

- [Lighthouse Testnet 0](https://github.com/eth2-clients/eth2-testnets/tree/master/lighthouse/testnet0)
- [Nimbus Testnet 0](https://github.com/eth2-clients/eth2-testnets/tree/master/nimbus/testnet0)
- [Nimbus Testnet 1](https://github.com/eth2-clients/eth2-testnets/tree/master/nimbus/testnet1)
- [Lighthouse Testnet 2](https://github.com/eth2-clients/eth2-testnets/tree/master/lighthouse/testnet2)

#### single-client testnets

Once the clients reach a certain maturity, clients release their testnets to the public and invite community members to participate in consensus by providing validators.

The first single-client testnets in early 2020 were:

- [Lighthouse Testnet 5](https://github.com/eth2-clients/eth2-testnets/tree/master/lighthouse/testnet5)
- [Prysm Sapphire](https://github.com/eth2-clients/eth2-testnets/tree/master/prysm/Sapphire(v0.9.4))
- [Prysm Topaz](https://github.com/eth2-clients/eth2-testnets/tree/master/prysm/Topaz(v0.11.1))
- [Prysm Onyx](https://github.com/eth2-clients/eth2-testnets/tree/master/prysm/Onyx(v0.12.1))

#### multi-client testnets

At some point, the different clients had to start to work together with regards to networking and consensus. The most critical part about multi-client testnets was ensuring that all clients properly implement the Eth2 specification.

The first multi-client testnets were:

- [Schlesi Testnet](https://github.com/goerli/medalla/tree/master/.trash/schlesi): Lighthouse and Teku
- [Witti Testnet](https://github.com/goerli/medalla/tree/master/witti): Prysm, Lighthouse, and Teku
- [Altona Testnet](https://github.com/goerli/medalla/tree/master/altona): Prysm, Lighthouse, Teku, and Nimbus
- [Medalla Testnet](https://github.com/goerli/medalla/blob/master/medalla):  Prysm, Lighthouse, Teku, Nimbus, and Lodestar
- [Spadina Testnet](https://github.com/goerli/medalla/blob/master/spadina): "dress rehearsal" testnet to practice mainnet launch procedure
- [Zinken Testnet](https://github.com/goerli/medalla/blob/master/zinken): "dress rehearsal" testnet to practice mainnet launch procedure

#### semi-public attacknets

Attack-networks are specially prepared testnets that should encourage testers to try breaking them.

Multiple tiers of bounties were available for breaking the following networks:

- [Single-client `beta-0` attacknets](https://github.com/ethereum/public-attacknets/tree/master/attacknets/beta-0)
- [Multi-client `beta-1` attacknets](https://github.com/ethereum/public-attacknets/tree/master/attacknets/beta-1)

#### post-launch testnets

Once the Ethereum 2.0 beacon chain launches, it's expected to see a new generation of testnets that serve the purpose to assist developers implementing applications and testing potential protocol upgrades.

#### other testing efforts

In addition to testnets, the following notable testing efforts have been conducted:

- [Multinet](https://github.com/eth2-clients/multinet): a collection of scripts to simulate multi-client testnets
- [Beacon Fuzz](https://github.com/sigp/beacon-fuzz): differential fuzzing framework for the Ethereum 2.0 clients