# What is the purpose of the Zinken Ethereum 2.0 testnet?

Tags: testnets, eth-2.0, beacon-chain, spadina

The Spadina testnet launched less than 2 days ago.

What is the purpose of the Zinken testnet? What is being covered that was not covered in Spadina?

Related:
[What are the Ethereum 2.0 testnets?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87917/what-are-the-ethereum-2-0-testnets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spadina and Zinken serve the entirely same purpose: practice a mainnet launch.

They are literally called "dress rehearsal" testnets. The reason we launch Zinken right after Spadina is that the Spadina launch was not as smoothly as desired.

There is a desire to have one testnet launch with high activity (> 70%) right from genesis slot 0. Both Medalla and Spadina failed that criteria.

Also, for both networks, Medalla and Spadina, clients had last minute "hotfix" releases which caused additional instability. This time we want to prepare a stable launch without any hiccups.

> If successful, we might see a mainnet genesis announcement soon.